# Side Mirror Hits Cover

Tags: skoda, wing-mirrors, octavia

I had a faulty indicator light on side mirror. In order to change it I had to remove the mirror. I did it, replace light with new one. But when I reassemble the mirror it looked weird. It does not look it stand right position in the case. Moreover when I adjust from electronic panel it hits the edges of the cover. Is there anything I can do about it? Like adjustment screws and so on.

2012 Skoda Octavia

photo detail edit:
You can see the highlighted points that adjustable mirror hitpoints. At some point the cover blocks mirror to move further. I suspect the cover did not fit well but when I bruteforce it doesn't move either.
[image]

Comment: Could you post a photo so that we can see what you mean? Ideally with a photo of the other side as well for comparison. I suspect it's caused by the mirror not seating properly back into position.